# Error al exportar de WorkBench a PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hice mi diagrama en WorkBench y cuando lo exporto como SQL aparece el codigo de abajo pero al cargarlo a phpmyadmin, me sale el error de la imagen, que puedo hacer, por favor soluciones claras gracias...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<html><pre>-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Tue Apr 30 20:28:55 2019
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema lvnm1654_11analytics
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema lvnm1654_11analytics
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `lvnm1654_11analytics` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `lvnm1654_11analytics` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`bodega`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`bodega` (
  `idBodega` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  `fechaCreacion` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBodega`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`inventario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`inventario` (
  `idInventario` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `responsable` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `cantidad` INT NULL,
  `fechaInventario` DATETIME NULL,
  `idBodega` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idInventario`),
  INDEX `idBodega` (`idBodega` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idBodega`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBodega`)
    REFERENCES `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`bodega` (`idBodega`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`proveedores`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`proveedores` (
  `idProveedores` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombreProveedor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `fechaCreacion` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProveedores`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`producto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`producto` (
  `idProducto` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombreProducto` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `categoriaProducto` INT NULL,
  `tallaProducto` INT NULL,
  `fechaCreacion` DATETIME NULL,
  `idProveedores` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idBodega` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`),
  INDEX `idProveedores` (`idProveedores` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `idBodega` (`idBodega` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idProveedores`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idProveedores`)
    REFERENCES `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`proveedores` (`idProveedores`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `idBodega`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBodega`)
    REFERENCES `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`bodega` (`idBodega`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
</pre></html>
```

Ayuda por favor necesito respuesta rapida...

Hice mi diagrama en WorkBench y cuando lo exporto como SQL aparece el codigo de abajo pero al cargarlo a phpmyadmin, me sale el error de la imagen, que puedo hacer, por favor soluciones claras gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los errores ocurren porque hay ciertas diferencias entre el Workbench de las últimas versiones y PHPMyAdmin.
Cambia las siguientes cosas.

> Si vas a exportar a MariaDB, cambia lo siguiente.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `lvnm1654_11analytics` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```

por

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `lvnm1654_11analytics` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```

Los índices por default vienen con el atributo VISIBLE, así que los puedes quitar para omitir los errores.

> -- Table `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`inventario`

```
INDEX `idBodega` (`idBodega` ASC) VISIBLE,
```

por

```
INDEX `idBodega` (`idBodega` ASC),
```

> -- Table `lvnm1654_11analytics`.`producto`

```
INDEX `idProveedores` (`idProveedores` ASC) VISIBLE,
INDEX `idBodega` (`idBodega` ASC) VISIBLE,
```

por

```
INDEX `idProveedores` (`idProveedores` ASC),
INDEX `idBodega` (`idBodega` ASC),
```